# Terminal State Classification with Hidden Markov Models

Tags: classification, unsupervised-learning, hidden-markov-model

The Viterbi algorithm predicts the most likely sequence of hidden states. But what if the variable of interest is the final hidden state? For example, predicting if a friend (whom you can't visit due to Covid) is **currently** ill or healthy using emission observations from a series of daily phone calls.

We can generate marginal hidden state distributions $p(z_T)$ at time T by running Monte Carlo simulations on the HMM structure, but I'm wondering is it possible to obtain this distribution **given** a set of observations $p(z_T|x_1, x_2, ..., x_T)$?

$p(z_T|x_1, x_2, ..., x_T) = \frac{p(x_1, x_2, ..., x_T|z_T) . p(z_T)}{p(x_1, x_2, ..., x_T)}$

If we apply Bayes’s formula as above, does it make sense to derive $p(x_1, x_2, ..., x_T|z_T)$ from the Backward algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

Estimating $p\left(z_T \mid x_{1\ldots T}\right)$ is called **[filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model#Filtering)**, and it’s a fundamental operation on HMMs. Filtering is estimation of the current state, given all observations up to this point. (Contrast it with smoothing: estimating a state based on past and future observations.)

You’d want to perform filtering with the **forward algorithm**, not the backward algorithm. Unlike the Monte Carlo approach, this gives an exact solution in polynomial time.

Comment: You're right. I was confused at first because the forward algorithm directly evaluates $p(z_T, x_{1...T})$, but $p(z_T | x_{1...T})$ can be obtained by simply normalising it to sum to 1 according to Bayes's Formula .

Comment: Even easier: according to the law of total probability.